# Git push command not working with msysgit setup

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit, msysgit

I installed GIT onto my windows 2k8 server following these directions: http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/HOWTO_CentralServerWindowsXP

All commands work fine except the "push" command. I get this error:

git.exe push -v  "origin" master:master

git: '/path/to/repo' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Pushing to user@ipaddress/path/to/repo
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the exact command you are running? How are your remotes set up? What protocol are you using (ssh, git, ...)?

Comment: The command I'm using: git.exe push -v  "origin" master:master  but I have also tried several different variations of this. I'm also using ssh

Comment: Can you post the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: origin gituser@5.16.217.81/d/private/test/ (fetch)
origin gituser@5.16.217.81/d/private/test/ (push)

Comment: are you able to open a plain SSH connection to `5.16.217.81`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the remote `origin` is not set up correctly.

I recommend re-creating that remote, either by renaming it or deleting it and making a new one:

```
git remote rename origin origin_backup
git remote add origin ssh://user:pass@address/path/to/repo.git
```

Then try again, preferably with a fetch before you push.

What protocol are you using? If `git://`, then make sure there is a Git daemon listening for connections. If `ssh://`, make sure you have ssh access and write permission on the appropriate directory tree.

Another possibility is that the server and client are running different versions of Git. It could cause problems if one is running a version that expects commands in the format `git cmd` and the other expects `git-cmd`.

Comment: I use ssh://. I don't see how origin is messed up if I can pull from it. I did as you suggested though and still does not work.

Comment: And you are certain you have write permission (by 'you' I mean the user as whom Git is running on the server)?

Comment: Yes, I have all the permissions set to modify (full access even). If it was a permission problem, wouldn't git just end the push instead of tell me the directory is not a function? Maybe it has something to do with my ssh?

Answer (score 1):

First check, if your plain SSH access to `5.16.217.81` is working: is

```
ssh 5.16.217.81
```

able to open a connection to the host?

If that is successful, ensure that you specify the path to your repo in a way your SSH server understands. In the [HowTo](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/HOWTO_CentralServerWindowsXP), the path is specified different from the path you typed:

- `5.16.217.81/d/private/test/` (your path) vs.
- `<server>:d:/DeeDriveRepos/Repo2`

Obviously, the CopSSH server wants colons to separate the drive letter from the host, so that your URL should be `5.16.217.81:d:/private/test/`.

If you used Cygwin, your URL would be `5.16.217.81/cygdrive/d/private/test/`

Answer (score 1):

My pushes work for msysgit version 1.6.5 but not for 1.7.x

Comment: for me the problem is 1.6.x versions cant CLONE to network locations...  Each version with it's own bug, how is that??